# ISS Mass breakdown

Tags: iss, nasa, mass

I'm looking for some solid numbers that break down the mass of the ISS into functional categories (with the goal of making a neat pie chart). Such categories might include the mass of...

- Docked reentry craft
- Consumables (food)
- Scientific experiments
- Power generation and thermal systems
- Structural components (truss structure)
- Pressurized modules
- LSS equipment
- etc.

Where might I find such data? Are there any pre-compiled lists? Additionally, because ISS mass changes with each arrival of a resupply craft, is there anywhere where the ISS's mass is tracked somewhat-live?

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 as far as I can tell, the website is non-functional

Comment: @Dragongeek I just noticed the 2nd answer to that question is the same as what I just wrote. So this may indeed be a duplicate.  I'm deleting my answer and voting to close as a duplicate.